# How does execv does it?

Tags: c, windows, exec

Perhaps this is an issue of magic. I'm trying to create a function that has the following signature(or equivalent const char *const *args)

```
void ExecuteJavaVM(char** args){
 
}
```

I want to emulate how `execv` handles an array of parameters, as you may know `execv` doesn't requires us to put the max number of elements of the array. It just magically counts the number of elements in the array we pass as its second parameter.

This is the execv signature.

```
intptr_t _execv( 
   const char *cmdname,
   const char *const *argv 
);
```

Somehow execv manages to "count" the number of elements in the array argv. This is exactly what I'm trying to do.

`sizeof` is almost useless, since the datatype of the array decays to a simple pointer, so `sizeof` will most probably always return 4.

Any ideas? Anyone knows where to find the sources of these functions for Windows?

Comment: "It just magically counts the number of elements in the array we pass as its second parameter." This is just wrong. Did you read the manual page?

Comment: +1. R. Martinho Fernandes is correct, and I've upvoted his/her answer, but judging by the signatures you quote, you took your information from [the woefully incomplete MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/886kc0as.aspx). I don't think that merits a downvote.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes To be fair the MSDN documentation on the `execv` function fails to mention that it is a NULL terminated array.

Comment: @john yeah, it took me a while to realize this was for the Windows POSIX emulation thingies. I thought it was for Cygwin or something. (and for that I changed my answer from referencing a Linux man page to referencing the POSIX docs).

Comment: @john: I checked out of curiosity... someone should have a serious talk with whoever wrote the documentation: *This POSIX function is deprecated beginning in Visual C++ 2005. Use the ISO C++ conformant _execv instead* WTF?

Comment: Yes, guys, you're right. I'm following the MSDN documentation. It fails to mention it's a NULL terminated array.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas As far as I know they are talking about the leading underscore. Names without a leading underscore are not allowed unless mandated by the C++ standard. That's no excuse for the inadequte documentation. The NULL termination is mentioned on the 'see here for examples' page however.

Comment: @avd: Windows is probably not the best platform to use POSIX

Comment: @john: It is the other way around they consider `execv` non conformant and `_execv` is the *conformant* replacement. In C++ names **with** a leading underscore, in the global namespace are *reserved for the implementation*, `execv` is as fine a name as `bar` or `foo`, while using `_execv` is actually bordering the limits... Is the POSIX layer library to be considered the *implementation*?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas That's what I said isn't it?

Comment: @john: I misread you, since what are reserved are the names starting with underscore (i.e. you cannot write `void _f()` in your program in the global namespace)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: as I understand thing, execv should indeed have a leading underscore because it is an implementation-specific function included in the runtime library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [POSIX docs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/exec.html) (emphasis mine):

> The argument `argv` is an array of character pointers to null-terminated strings. **The application shall ensure that the last member of this array is a null pointer.** These strings shall constitute the argument list available to the new process image. The value in `argv[0]` should point to a filename that is associated with the process being started by one of the exec functions.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The documentation in msdn doesn't talk about this requirement. But it all makes sense, that explains the forced NULL parameter in their variable parameter counterparts.